What should I tell my company the reason for leaving? When I am just accepting a direct offer from company's client
I currently work for a company who promised me that they pay me 80% of what my clients pay them but then i got to know that they only pay me 20% and keeps the 80%.
Now my client wants me to be their direct employee, so is it ethical for me to leave the company and join my client and what reason should I give to my company and what reason should client give them for leaving?
They have a very negative environment so it is for sure to not mention that we are getting direct.

Please don't use all caps. It is the internet equivalent of shouting. Please edit the question to use normal capitalization.

Your employer is going to find out when you eventually represent them.

First, you should carefully read any documents (contracts) that you signed with your current company before joining the client.
You can join the client if both of the followings are true:

You don't have any contractural requirement with your company that
prevents you from joining the client.
The client doesn't have any agreement with your company that
prevents the client from taking or hiring your company's employees.  --- BTW, you can probably ask the client to see if they have any agreement like that with your company.



What reason should I give to my company ?

You don't need to give any reason.


What reason should client give them for leaving?

This is the client's concern. This is not your concern.
Usually, the client does not need to give any reason. But, this is between the client and your company. You don't have to worry about this.


Is it ethical for me to leave the company ?

I don't see any ethical issue in this case.
